# Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma aplicação com spring boot com acesso ao banco de dados mysql utilizando JdbcTemplate e quando tento acesso via url os dados do banco sempre me retorna o erro:

**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Dec 19 12:32:45 BRST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

**Classe Funcionario**

```
public class Funcionario implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer codigo;
private String nome;
private String cargo;
private Integer idade;

private Departamento departamento;

public Funcionario() {
    super();
}
//getter e setters omitidos
```

**Desafio2Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Desafio2Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Desafio2Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**ServletInitializer**

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder    application) {
    return application.sources(Desafio2Application.class);
}

}
```

**FuncionarioDaoImpl**

```
@Repository
public class FuncionarioDaoImpl implements FuncionarioDao{

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate;
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> findAll() {
    return JdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from Funcionario");
}
}
```

**FuncionarioController**

```
@RestController
public class FuncionarioController {
@Autowired
FuncionarioService funcionarioService;

@RequestMapping("/funcionarios")
public List<Map<String, Object>> findAll(){
    return funcionarioService.findAll();
}
}
```

**FuncionarioServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class FuncionarioServiceImpl implements FuncionarioService{

@Autowired
private FuncionarioDao funcionarioDao;

@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> findAll() {
    return this.funcionarioDao.findAll();
}
}
```

Estou começando agora com Spring e não tenho muita expiriencia... ja procurei algumas soluções mas não consegui resolver o problema que é mostrar na tela via url a lista dos funcionarios..
Desde já obrigado

Comment: Qual a url você está tentando acessar?

Comment: No application.properties você pode definir o contexto e porta.

Comment: No application.properties adicionar essas 2 propriedades:

server.contextPath=/teste
server.port=9080

Caminho da págiana:

...\src\main\webapp\login.xhtml



A url ficaria: http://localhost:9080/teste/login.xhtml

Comment: A url seria localhost:8080/funcionarios. Consegui resolver o problema que em uma reorganização na estrutura do projeto o spring conseguiu mapear a url.